# Index data to ElasticSearch with Firebase functions, not all fields are indexed

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase function to push data to ElasticSearch to be indexed. But sometimes the data set is not indexed completely. Which fields can be indexed seem to be a random behavior, sometimes all fields are indexed, sometimes only a few, sometimes only one.

The firebase function I used to push data to Elastic search as below:

```
exports.indexHashtagsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/valid_hashtags/{hashtag_id}')
.onWrite(event =>{

    let hashtagData = event.data.val();
    let hashtag_id = event.params.hashtag_id;

    console.log('Indexing the hashtags: ', hashtagData);

    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'hashtags/hashtag/' + hashtag_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = hashtagData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        url: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth:{
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password
        },
        body: hashtagData,
        json: true
    };

    return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
        console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
    });

});
```

according to this log `console.log('Indexing the hashtags: ', hashtagData);` sometimes the dataset is not coming through in full. However the dataset created on database is complete and correct.

Any idea what went wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: in case anyone sees this, I have solved this by changing the way I add data onto database. Before it was added one sub node by one sub node. I created a separate model to add all sub nodes at once and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the fields to index on your request.

```
let elasticSearchFields = ['field1','field2','field3',...'fieldn'];
```

Then in your request you should add the following

```
...
body:  _.pick(hashtagData , elasticSearchFields ),
...
```

Hope that will work